# Get Path of Uploaded File using Python

Tags: python, upload

Is it possible to get the full path of the file on the user's computer being uploaded to my site?

Using `os.path.abspath(fileitem.filename)` simply gets me the address of where my script is executing from on my shared hosting server.

FYI: fileitem = form['file']  and form = cgi.FieldStorage()

Answer (score 5):

No, that information isn't sent by the user, so it's not available on your end

Comment: It seems it could be done with Javascript. A function could read the browse field path, put it in a hidden textfield and submit it with the form?

Comment: JavaScript runs on the remote user's end. Python runs on your CGI server. What you say is true, you could combine the two technologies.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer - IE <= 7 used to send full file path instead of filename only, but IE 8 changed the default setting and sends only file **names** for [privacy reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx).

Even if client did send the full file **path**, many web-based solutions (e.g PHP, Django) will strip the path and leave only filename, protecting the application against [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) attacks. Python's cgi library is not one of them though.

So - yes, you're able to get the full file path with Python cgi, but only if client sent it using IE <= 7.